# How do you start a minimized MS-DOS session on Windows 98 SE?

Tags: windows, ms-dos, windows-98

How do you start a minimized MS-DOS session (i.e., launch a Command Prompt window that is in the minimized state) for Windows 98 [version 4.10.2222]?

I thought the solution would be:

```
start /min
```

But this doesn't work for me. I have no idea why.

As I understand, there is a more specific command for this particular version and it is a bit shorter but I have not been able to find any manual for the Windows 98 MS-DOS.

Comment: On Windows 9x, you probably need a PIF file for this, rather than `start /min`.

Answer (score 5):

`start /min command` works fine at any Windows 9x command line (in an existing command prompt window, a batch file, the Run window) and will start the command prompt minimised; although the `start` command itself may open a console window in the foreground.

If you instead launch the command prompt from a PIF file, this can be configured in the file properties window:

[image: MS-DOS Prompt Properties window, with a ‘Run:’ combo box pulled down, revealing options: ‘Normal window’, ‘Minimized’, ‘Maximized’. The middle one is selected.]